# Python cannot import CSV using DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Pandas to import some csv file into Python.

my code is:

```
import pandas as pd  
data_df = pd.read_csv('highfrequency2.csv')
print data_df.head()
```

but there is always an error message:

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Python\sdfasdfasdfasdfasdf.py", line 7, in <module>
import pandas as pd
  File "G:\Python\pandas.py", line 9, in <module>
from pandas import DataFrame
ImportError: cannot import name DataFrame**
```

Can some one figure out why ? Many thanks !!!

Comment: Is there a reason you need to import it?, if you remove that line does it work?

Comment: Could you specify pandas and python version?

Comment: @zom-pro Python 2.72. I am scripting under Spyder. How can I see the pandas version ?

Comment: @EdChum sorry, remove which line ?

Comment: `from pandas import DataFrame`, you can get pandas version using `print(pd.__version__)`

Comment: I tested it and I'm able to import DataFrame and it also works without the line as EdChum said.

Comment: @zom-pro   I typed the code your gave me. It said: **cannot import name DataFrame**. I am not sure I can get it updated cos I am using school's desktop.

Comment: Sorry are you saying it works without `from pandas import DataFrame` correct? it seems unnecessary to have that line

Comment: @EdChum. Thanks. Why that line should be removed ? I copied this syntax from some online-tutorial...

Comment: Well unless you're trying to create a dataframe like this `DataFrame(...)` as opposed to `pd.DataFrame(...)` then to me it's unnecessary, in your code snippet above you are not calling the `DataFrame` constructor explicitly, `read_csv` returns one, so to me it's unnecessary

Comment: @zom-pro  sorry for confusing... I just typed  `import pandas as pd`
`print(pd.__version__)`   and system still gave me `ImportError: cannot import name DataFrame`

Comment: NO remove the line `from pandas import DataFrame` I think this is not necessary

Comment: @EdChum yeah, I removed that line. but its still not working.

Comment: your pandas install is corrupted. How did you install it?

Comment: @zom-pro I am running Python on school's desktop. I have on idea how did they install the Python.

Comment: not good. Do you need to open the csv with pandas or you just want to open the csv?

Comment: thank your anyway. I will check the pandas pack and the version

Comment: I want to open csv with Pandas so that I can do some data manipulation.

Comment: You do from pandas import DataFrame and not from pd import DataFrame ? Since you have imported pandas as pd the latter may work better.. But as others suggested it seems that perhaps you have a bad install of Pandas on the python installation

Comment: thanks @dartdog. In my Spyder, there some exclamation mark tell me that   `Pandas imported but unused`. I am still confusing whether I have Pandas in my desktop.

Answer (score 3):

It look like you've called one of your *own* programs `pandas`:

```
G:\Python\pandas.py
```

So this is the one Python is trying to import, and the one which doesn't have a DataFrame object.

Rename your program, delete any cached objects (`pandas.pyc` or `pandas.pyo`), and restart your Python interpreter.